# AWS Quicksight render long string as pretty printed json

Tags: formatting, string-formatting, amazon-quicksight

In an AWS Quicksight dashboard I have a need to display JSON in human readable pretty printed format. I have so far been able to display the JSON as a string but since there are no line breaks it is very hard to read.

Instead of seeing something like:

```
{
  "key1": "value",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": ["item1", "item2"]
}
```

I only get something like this:

```
{<br>"key1": "value", <br>  "key2": "value2", <br>  "key3": ["item1", "item2"] <br>}
```

I found this https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/rendering-long-strings-greater-than-2-047-characters/3619 post on the Quicksight forum but that only focuses on rendering long strings, not formatting of the string.